# Proper way to cast an enum to Type in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular `enum` like this:

```
export enum ProtectiveClassificationType
{
  InflationAdjustedNominal =1,
  NominalInflationAdjusted =2,
  InflationAdjusted =3,
  Nominal =4,
  None = 5
}
```

and 2 methods. One to get the description of an enum item and the other one to return the enum as a <key, value> pair to use it into select lists:

```
export interface SelectPayload {
 key: string | number;
 value: string;
}

  protected enumToList(type: Type, nameResolver: (element: number) => string): SelectPayload[] {
        const retList: SelectPayload[] = [];
        const values = Object.values(type);
        for (const value of values.slice(values.length / 2))
        retList.push({ key: value, value: nameResolver(value) });
        return retList;
    }//enumToList


  public getProtectiveClassificationByType(type: number): string {
    switch (type) {
      case ProtectiveClassificationType.InflationAdjusted: return "Inflation Adjusted";
      case ProtectiveClassificationType.InflationAdjustedNominal: return "Inflation Adjusted then Nominal";
      case ProtectiveClassificationType.Nominal: return "Nominal";
      case ProtectiveClassificationType.NominalInflationAdjusted: return "Nominal then Inflation Adjusted";
      case ProtectiveClassificationType.None: return "None";
      default: return "Unknown";
    }
  }

  public  getProtectiveClassificationTypeToList(): SelectPayload[] {       
    return this.enumToList(ProtectiveClassificationType as unknown as Type, this.getProtectiveClassificationByType.bind(this));      
  }//getProtectiveClassificationTypeToList
```

The method `enumToList` is from a base class and in order to use it I have to do such a cast `ProtectiveClassificationType as unknown as Type`. For me it doesn't look right and now my question is if there is a better way to do it. PS: "Type" is from "import { Type } from "typescript";

Comment: In the `enumToList` fn, can you find out what the definition for `type: Type` is? We need to know the shape of that type before we can help.

Comment: @Robert Rendell - The Type is from - import { Type } from "typescript"; That function has a general purpose to be able to work with any kind of enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

Your solution is the only one that will work without making changes to `enumToList` function, because `import { Type } from "typescript"` doesn't overlap with `enum`.

```js
ProtectiveClassificationType as unknown as Type
```

#### Refactoring Solution

This involves changing the enumToList method to use generics, then later when you use the function, don't specify the type in the generics, however your linter may complain. Although, this solution is the equivalent to using `any` which removes the type safety but then again, so does forcing the type of the enum to be `Type` when they don't overlap.

```js
protected enumToList<T>(enum: T, nameResolver: (element: number) => string): SelectPayload[] {
      const retList: SelectPayload[] = [];
      const values = Object.values(enum);
      for (const value of values.slice(values.length / 2))
      retList.push({ key: value, value: nameResolver(value) });
      return retList;
  }//enumToList

...

public getProtectiveClassificationTypeToList(): SelectPayload[] {       
  return this.enumToList(ProtectiveClassificationType, this.getProtectiveClassificationByType.bind(this));      
}//getProtectiveClassificationTypeToList
```

Comment: Is not working. I get error: 'enumToList', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010) Can u show me a working example in stackblitz?

Comment: https://shorturl.at/bcFQY